# React native elements form Secure text entry

Tags: react-native

I want to use a react native elements form for a text input for user passwords. My code is here:

```
<FormLabel> Passsword </FormLabel>
<FormInput 
onChangeText - {(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
/>
```

How can I make the text they enter secure so nobody can see what it is.
For textInput they have `secureTextEntry` but I have not been able to find something similar for react native elements

Comment: You can use a package like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hide-show-password-input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React Native Elements FormInput does not support secureTextEntry. Just add a TextInput instead of a FormInput it will work the same and look the same if styled correctly.

Comment: Currently it does support it. See an answer below from fellow poster.

Answer (score 33):

React Native Elements Input **inherits** all native TextInput props from React Native:

see: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/input.html#props

So this works fine:

```js
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements'

<Input placeholder="password" secureTextEntry={true} />
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `TextInput`'s property `secureTextEntry` for to hide the password field

```
            <TextInput
                   .....
                    secureTextEntry={true}  
                />
```

This field accepts `boolean` value `true`  for hide the text and `false` for to show the text

Comment: So I would replace FormInput with TextInput?

Comment: According to my knowledge this is the simple easy and best way and text input comes with so many other event so .. yes  replace and try and if you find any batter option then go with that and don't forgot let me know

Answer (score 2):

I think FormInput does support secureTextEntry. Pass it as a prop to ..

```
    <FormInput
      {...props}
      style={StyleSheet.flatten([
        style,
      marginTop={marginTop}
      autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
      autoCorrect={autoCorrect}
      secureTextEntry={true}
      ...
    />
```

FormInput inherits all native TextInput props that come with a standard React Native TextInput element. We're using FormInput with secureTextEntry as a prop in our project. You may want to see: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/forms.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more props in your custom component for secure the text.

```
<FormLabel> Passsword </FormLabel>
<FormInput 
isSecure={true}
onChangeText - {(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
/>
```

In your class, you need to get the props and pass into your **TextInput** property.

```
    <TextInput
       secureTextEntry={this.props.isSecure ? this.props.isSecure : false}  
    />
```

You can check about secureTextEntry from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#securetextentry).

Comment: Adding the isSecure = {true} did not work on its own. When you say to add the TextInput to my class where would that be exactly. I want to use the FormInput to take in text from the user.

Comment: What are you using in FormInput??

Comment: The isSecure = {true}, and the onChangeText. Do I put the TextInput in there too?

Comment: Yeah, you need to pass in secureTextEntry type in TextInput.

Comment: When I put the TextInput in the FormInput I get a syntax error

Comment: Can you share your FormInput at here?  So we can check.

Comment: <FormInput
onChangeText = {(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
isSecure = {true}
<TextInput
secureTextEntry = {this.props.isSecure ? this.props.isSecure : false}
/>
/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176340/discussion-between-nirmalsinh-and-paulgio).

Answer (score 1):

```
do keyboardType="default" and it will work. It worked for me.


  <TextInput
                        style={[styles.textInput]}
                        placeholder=""
                        secureTextEntry={hidePassword}
                        selectionColor={'#000'}
                        editable={true}
                        returnKeyType={'next'}
                        keyboardType="default"
                        autoFocus={false}
                        autoCapitalize={'characters'}
                        placeholderTextColor="rgb(153,153,153)"
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.onCurrentPassTextChange(text)}
                      >{currentPassword}</TextInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and resolved it by adding the following to the `<Input />`:

```
multiline={false} <------THIS
secureTextEntry={true}
```

secureTextEntry does not work with a multiline input per the react-native docs. So react-native-elements obviously defaults to a multiline input. Setting multiline to false worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**By using this code you can secure Input Field**

```
<TextInput
                   secureTextEntry={true}
                   placeholder = "Enter your password"
                   autoCorrect={false}
                    style={{ height: 44, width: '92%', marginTop: 20, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, paddingLeft: 15, borderRadius: 7}}
                    />
```